# Trigger to delete past records in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, database

I want only to maintain present 1 month records log details. need to delete past record log details.I tried this code however could not work this,

```
create sequence userseq1;

CREATE TABLE users
( id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('userseq1'::regclass) 
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES(126);

CREATE TABLE History
( userid integer
, createdate timestamp
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION recordcreatetime() RETURNS trigger language plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO History values(new.id,NOW() );
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER user_hist
BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE procedure recordcreatetime();
```

However it is working to insert values sequencing one by one adding.I want to delete the previous 1 month record Log details.I tried this below code and it is not working

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trf_keep_row_number_steady()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$body$
DECLARE
BEGIN
        IF (SELECT count(createdate) FROM history) > rownum_limit
    THEN 
        DELETE FROM history
        WHERE createdate = (SELECT min(createdate) FROM history);        
    END IF;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_keep_row_number_steady 
AFTER INSERT ON history
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trf_keep_row_number_steady();
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see in your second code block, you have a trigger on `history` table and you are trying to `DELETE FROM history` in that same trigger.

**Insert / Update / Delete on a table through a trigger on the same table is not allowed.** Please think of some other alternative, e.g., running a separate `DELETE` statement for the required cleanup of rows before or after your main `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried but it is not working.Could you provide any docs or sample code for this.......

Comment: Actually postgresql allows this. But @Patrick should provide an error message instead of "it's not working". At first glance the function is syntactically incorrect anyway because of this `rownum_limit` defined nowhere.